# Moving millions of records between Oracle and MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, data-migration

I have an Oracle database with a table (30 columns, no BLOBs or LOBs) that has approx. 50 million records. I need to move the data into MSSQL. Table structure will remain the same on the MSSQL side. What is the preferred method of moving large amounts of data? Export then import or write a small application to do the load? Or other methods (free or commercial tools)?

Comment: Are all the data types compatible? Have you looked at SSIS?

Comment: One time? Link server, copy via sql command. SQL Server: use SSIS and set up a data pump, totally free (it is part of sql server, which you have anyway).

Comment: Raj: types are compatible, only integer, date and varchar are used.
TomTom: this is a one time migration. My concern is how to handle dropped connections or errors during migration? How do I know where I need to resume in case of an error?

Comment: TomTom: This Data Flow Task is looking good. Post your comment as answer and I'll mark it accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/oracle-sqlserver-goldengate-460262.html) tool to replicate data.

Comment: Answers that rely on links alone are rarely of value.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Integration Services. A simple data flow should do: Use your Oracle database as an OLE DB Source and your SQL Server Database as an OLE DB Destination.

Avoid using "SQL Server Destination". I have experienced slower performance compared to using OLE DB.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best approaches is pushing from Oracle to text files with sqlplus and SPOOL and loading to MSSQL with bcp utility. Speedy and robust :)

Comment: Hmmm, unless you have data with carriage returns, or other content that interferes with the expected file format.

Comment: You will always have a possibility to use quotations for text fields ;)

Comment: How about text fields that contain quotations? Possibly an odd number of them, with a few commas? :)

Comment: How about info from Wiki?
- Each record "should" contain the same number of comma-separated fields.
- Any field may be quoted (with double quotes).
- Fields containing a line-break, double-quote, and/or commas should be quoted. (If they are not, the file will likely be impossible to process correctly).
- A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two (double) quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

50M in a single table is an easy task for SSIS. If it's a one-off task I wouldn't try anything else.